# Error while performing arithmetic operation on pointer to array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, structure

I am using the below program to save bank account information. I have also added an option, deposit. Once the user selects the deposit option, the deposit function will ask for the account number and cehck if it is in the records. If it is in the records, it will ask for deposit amount. But I can not add the deposit amount to the balance of that account. It shows either indirection error when I use 
`(*(acc_no+loop)).balance = (*(acc_no+loop)).balance+deposit`

If i use `(acc_no+loop)->balance = (acc_no+loop)->balance + deposit;`, it shows balance must point to struct or union error.

Here is my code:

```
    void deposit(struct bank *acc_data)
    {
        long acc_no;
        int loop;
        int deposit;

        transaction:
        printf("Enter Account #:");
        scanf("%ld",&acc_no);

        for(loop=0;loop<200;loop++)
        {
            if ((acc_data+loop)->acc_no == acc_no)
            {
                printf("Enter the deposit amount:");
                scanf("%d", &deposit);

                (acc_no+loop)->balance = (acc_no+loop)->balance + deposit;
            }
            else if (loop == 199)
            {
                printf("No account found. Try again\n");
                break;
                goto transaction;
            }
        }
    }

    void edit_data(struct bank *acc_data)
    {
        int loop;
        struct bank
        {
            long acc_no;
            char name[80];
            int balance;
        };
        for(loop=0;loop<200;loop++)
        {
            (acc_data+loop)->acc_no = 1000+loop;
            strcpy((acc_data+loop)->name,"Name");
            (acc_data+loop)->balance = 1000;
        } 

    }

int main()
{
    int loop;
    int transaction_option;
    struct bank data[200];

    edit_data(data);

option:

    printf("\n\nPlease select an option:\t 1. Deposit\t ");
    scanf("%d", &transaction_option);

    switch(transaction_option)
    {
    case 1:
        deposit(data);
        break;

default:
        printf("Invalid Entry. Try again");
        goto option;
        break;
    }


return 1;
}
```

Comment: `break; goto transaction;`? Are you a fan of `goto fail;`?

Comment: u spotted a bug..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot dereference

```
(acc_no+loop)
```

because these variables are both **integer** types - **not** pointers. It looks like your code should be changed to

```
(acc_data+loop)->balance = (acc_data+loop)->balance + deposit;
```

as `acc_data` is actually a pointer (unlike `acc_no`) and the resulting pointer arithmetic will work as you want it to. This of course will only work if your functions input argument

```
struct bank *acc_data
```

actually points to an **array** of your `bank` structs (which appears to be the case from your `main` code).

Comment: oh...it seems that i was careless with the variable. Thank you.